# Using Radio Buttons to set labels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

So for class I'm suppose to make a Celsius to Fahrenheit converter GUI. With that said, it's a pretty simple and easy program to create. I want to do more with it though. What I want to do is have one window that changes depending on which radio button is selected in a buttongroup. I want the selected radiobutton for "To Fahrenheit" or "To Celsius" to update the labels for the input and output. I have tried using an actionlistener for when one is selected, but it doesn't change the labels. Am I using the wrong listener? What's the correct way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Converter extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField tfNumber;
private JLabel lblCelsius;
private JLabel lblFahrenheit;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Converter frame = new Converter();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Converter() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setTitle("Celsius Converter");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 308, 145);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    tfNumber = new JTextField();
    tfNumber.setText("0");
    tfNumber.setBounds(10, 11, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(tfNumber);
    tfNumber.setColumns(10);

    lblCelsius = new JLabel("Celsius");
    lblCelsius.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblCelsius.setBounds(143, 12, 127, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblCelsius);

    lblFahrenheit = new JLabel("Fahrenheit");
    lblFahrenheit.setBounds(187, 46, 95, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblFahrenheit);

    final JLabel lblNum = new JLabel("32.0");
    lblNum.setBounds(143, 46, 43, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNum);

    final JRadioButton rdbtnF = new JRadioButton("to Fahrenheit");
    rdbtnF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(rdbtnF.isSelected()) {
                lblCelsius.setText("Celsius");
                lblFahrenheit.setText("Fahrenheit");
            }
        }
    });
    rdbtnF.setSelected(true);
    rdbtnF.setBounds(10, 72, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnF);

    final JRadioButton rdbtnC = new JRadioButton("to Celsius");
    rdbtnC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(rdbtnF.isSelected()) {
                lblCelsius.setText("Fahrenheit");
                lblFahrenheit.setText("Celsius");
            }
        }
    });
    rdbtnC.setBounds(121, 72, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnC);

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(rdbtnF);
    bg.add(rdbtnC);



    JButton btnConvert = new JButton("Convert");
    btnConvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(rdbtnF.isSelected()) {
                String num = String.valueOf(convertToF(tfNumber.getText()));
                lblNum.setText(num);
            }
            if(rdbtnC.isSelected()) {
                String num = String.valueOf(convertToC(tfNumber.getText()));
                lblNum.setText(num);
            }
        }
    });
    btnConvert.setBounds(10, 42, 123, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnConvert);
}

private double convertToF(String celsius) {
    double c = Double.parseDouble(celsius);
    double fahren = c * (9/5) + 32;
    return fahren;
}

private double convertToC(String fahren) {
    double f = Double.parseDouble(fahren);
    double celsius = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
    return celsius;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"So for class I'm suppose to make .. it's a pretty simple and easy program to create. I want to do more with it though."*  ***Why?***

Comment: Simple, to learn. But I made a small error that wasn't allowing to work. Forgot to change this: 
if(rdbtnF.isSelected()) to if(rdbtnC.isSelected())

It works now

Comment: Yeah, I just saw your typo as well. Your main problem though is the names of your JLabels are misleading and your use of absolute positioning and not use of layout managers.

Comment: @Opzoleet Please try not to post code in the comments. It's extremely difficult to read. Thank you. :) Ahaha Copy & Paste strikes again.

Comment: @AndrewG: it's a moot point. He's already solved his problem.\

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah just noticed haha.

Comment: I would change `lblCelsius` to `lblConvertFrom` and the other `lblConvertTo`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't decide to do more until I got done with it. Going back to change attribute names. Thanks for looking at it everyone!